# I have a pdf file in raw folder. How to show this pdf file into a webview?

Tags: android, pdf, raw

I have a file named as "policy" in R.raw folder. I want to show this file inside a webview so that user can view this file inside it.

Comment: I finally got the inputstream of that raw file and used a pdf viewer library: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer and it is working good.

Comment: Well done. So you know by now that a WebView cannot display a pdf document to begin with.